# reference only last match in str_extract_all in R

Tags: r, string, tidyverse

I have some code that is parsing some text and I have a sticking point with my regex expression sometimes capturing two things instead of one due to wonky data.

```
temp <- "abc abcdef"
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(temp,"ab.+")
[[1]]
[1] "abc abcdef"

str_extract_all(temp,"ab.+")[[1]][2]
[1] NA
```

Above is a simple example that I am working with. when I rapply this function, I may get 1,2 or 3 matches. The last match will be most important for my usage but I am not sure how to reference it.

Comment: You could use `dplyr::last` to pull out the last entry

Comment: Please, show the expected result. Currently, your regular expression returns all characters after (and including) the first "ab" encountered. So, there is only one element in the list returned by `str_extract_all()`. Perhaps, you need to amend the regex?

Answer (score 2):

As I understand, you mean something like

```
txt <- "bag of flour"
str_extract_all(txt, "\\b[a-z]+\\b")
# [[1]]
# [1] "bag"   "of"    "flour"
```

and referring to "flour". In that case you may use

```
tail(str_extract_all(txt, "\\b[a-z]+\\b")[[1]], 1)
# [1] "flour"
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use for example:

```
str_extract_all(temp,"ab.+")[[length(str_extract_all(temp,"ab.+"))]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Not very elegant but it gets the job done:

```
. <- str_extract_all(temp,".*?(?=(ab)|$)")[[1]]
paste0("a",.[[length(.)-1]])
# [1] "abcdef"
```

Or maybe you wanted something like this if your output can be only a word ?

```
. <- str_extract_all(temp,"\\bab.+?\\b")[[1]]
dplyr::last(.)
#[1] "abcdef"
```